# Height in GNSS in acquiring and postprocessing data

Tags: gps

First I am kind of a newbie using GNSS receivers and processing the data (I am an archaeologist). We acquired a couple of emlid reach rs+ receivers. Our first experiment was to set up a base for PPK postprocessing. We acquired 4 hours of data, corrected with data from our local airport data (via CORS). The postprocessing was made using RTKPOST. We obtained a lat/lon/height coordinate. We know that coordinates are in lat/lon WGS84 and that the heights are ellipsoidal. We know that we can use UNAVCO Geoid height calculator to get orthometric heights. Now is when the discussion begins. We set up a series of points and logged data for an hour with the rover. Base was in the previously calculated point and was set up to acquire data with manually defined coordinates, the original ones with ellipsoidal heights. The questions derived from the discussion with my colleagues are:

When setting up the base in the known point, Do I use the ellipsoidal or the orthometric height?

When postprocessing, Do I use the ellipsoidal or orthometric heights?

I know there are two questions here, but I think they are closely related.
Thanks before hand 
Gerardo

Comment: When you post-process, your coordinates are usually in the same coordinate reference system as the CORS points that are used so some flavor of ITRF or the country's current CRS, not WGS 84.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are setting a base GPS for post-processing, you only need to specify the coordinates of the base point in the software when doing the post-processing. It is usually not needed to be set on the receiver. Nevertheless, even if it is set on the receiver, the post-processing software should allow you to change the values before running the calculation. The correct base station coordinates are needed when working in RTK and if you need orthometric heights in the field, you would need a geoid file. Now the answer to whether to use ellipsoidal or orthometric is it depends on the data you have. Knowing that

> H = h + N

where H is orthometric height, h is ellipsoidal height and N is geoidal separation, which can be either positive or negative.

The processing is done based on the ellipsoidal height and you end up obtaining the results in ellipsoidal height for all measured points. After that, you apply the GS values to every point. If you know the GS at the base station and you are operating in a small range, you can apply the same GS for the calculated point. What is a small range is difficult to set as the geoid is obviously invisible and there is no way of knowing its fluctuations unless looking at the data.

There is also an option in some post-processing software to select a geoid file so the correction is done automatically.

Comment: We conducted an experiment today with your suggestions. I keep you posted with our results. Main thing I can download data from airport and  INEGI until tomorrow